# Delete localStorage, databaseStorage for a tab in Chrome/Chromium

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to delete all storage data from an tab when it's going to close. I found an extension which deletes cookies. But as I am a total newbie in extension writing I would like a hint where to look in the docs localStorage purge.

When a tab is removed the background.js gets the callback onRemoved with tabId. I can get the Tab object for the id.. However I have yet to find how one should remove items from localStorage or databaseStorage.

The w3c docs mention localStorage.clear(). How do I trigger this in the right context (in the tab and not in the background process)?

UPDATE: to clarify the central goal, I am looking for a way to restrict or reconstruct calls of methods chrome.browsingData.removeLocalStorage/removeIndexedDB/removeWebSQL only onto the closed tab/domain

Thank you,
pingi

Comment: So in a line your question is "How do I delete localStorage in a page from a chrome extension?"?

Comment: `window.onunload = function() {localStorage.clear();}`

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the beforeunload event in JavaScript.

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() 
{
localStorage.removeItem(key);
return '';
};
```

NOTE: The *onbeforeunload* method should return a string.

Comment: I want it to be called for each tab the user closes and I don't have the list of items (or keys) which the webpage set..

Comment: or you can use this window.onbeforeunload = function(){localStorage.clear();};